# C++ calling a method outside a class from inside a class

Tags: c++, class

I have a c++ program like this:

```
class KbdRptParser : public KeyboardReportParser
{
        void PrintKey(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);

protected:
        virtual void OnControlKeysChanged(uint8_t before, uint8_t after);

    virtual void OnKeyDown  (uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnKeyUp    (uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnKeyPressed(uint8_t key);
};

//ommitted stuff here

void KbdRptParser::OnKeyPressed(uint8_t key)
{
    keypress(key);

};

void keypress(uint8_t key)
{
    //do stuff...
}

//rest of program...
```

I want to be able to call `keypress` from inside `KbdRptParser::OnKeyPressed`, because there are global variables that won't work if i put the code from `keypress` into `KbdRptParser::OnKeyPressed`. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Well first you can just call it using `keypress`. Did you even try? If you wanna be specific to call the one in global namespace, use `::keypress`. Secondly you can put that in the class. It has no problem access global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare it before the

void keypress(unit8_t key);

void KbdRptParser::OnKeyPressed(uint8_t key)
{

}

Personal suggestion, and to follow pure Object oriented way, declare keypress as static function of a class and global variables as extern

Answer (score 2):

Just need to declare it before you call it.

Add this line at the top, or before the OnKeyPressed implementation:

```
void keypress(uint8_t key);
```

That just lets the compiler know, this method doesn't exist yet, but by the time the whole program is linked, it'll be there.